# Loop while sendo ignorado

Tags: python

Olá gostaria de obter ajuda a uma questão que não tenho achado resposta, eu tenho 2 loops while sendo ignorados sem alguma explicação (não dá erro simplesmente ela passa para o próximo), é preciso que o usuário insira um valor float de horas dentro de um período entre 0 a 24 horas e insira um valor inteiro em dias entre 1 a 31 no entanto as condições estão sendo ignoradas (já comentei a parte acima desse loop no entanto mesmo assim é ignorado, além disso pelo que procurei a condição está correta), o primeiro loop relacionado a potência de um aparelho está correto e está funcionando porém os outros 2 não.

```
 #while (potenciaDoArCondicionado <= 0):  # Impossibilita da potência ser negativa ou 0
                #potenciaDoArCondicionado = int(input("Qual a potência desse Ar-condicionado? "))
                #potenciaDoArCondicionado = (potenciaDoArCondicionado/1000) #Fórmula que faz a conversão de Watts para Quilowatt
            horasDoArCondicionado = 0  # Essa variável guarda quantas horas se utiliza o Ar Condicionado

            while(horasDoArCondicionado<=0 and horasDoArCondicionado>24):
                horasDoArCondicionado = float(input("Quantas horas por dia se utiliza este Ar-condicionado desse setor? "))

            diasDoArCondicionado = 0  # Essa variável guarda quantos dias no mês se utiliza o Ar Condicionado
            while(diasDoArCondicionado<1 and diasDoArCondicionado>31):
                diasDoArCondicionado = int(input("Quantas dias no mês se utiliza o Ar-condicionado desse setor? "))
```

Comment: Como é que algo pode ser "menor/igual a zero **E** maior que 24" ao mesmo tempo? Mesma coisa para a data, como é que um dia pode ser "menor que um **E** maior que 31"? Me dê um exemplo de valor que atenda qualquer uma  dessas situações que usou.  Obviamente que são condições que sempre serão falsas, portanto não atende o requisito para que ocorra o while.

Comment: Então seria or correto?

Comment: "AND" significa "E" (enquanto for menor que um E maior que trinta e um repita a pergunta), "OR" significa "OU" (enquanto for menor que um OU maior que trinta e um repita  a pergunta). Qual delas representa corretamente a sua intenção?

Comment: Eu preciso que o usuário insira um valor maior que 0 em horas (porque posteriormente usarei esse valor para um cálculo de consumo) e que esse valor não ultrapasse 24 horas. O mesmo para os dias, tem que ser maior que 1 dia e que não ultrapasse 31 dias

Comment: E qual das duas frases que eu disse representa isso que acaba de dizer?  Cuidado que você afirmou o que você precisa, mas no loop está tratando o que  "não precisa" (ou seja, repete a pergunta enquanto o valor  estiver insatisfatório)

Comment: Pelo que eu aprendi até o momento para que as minhas duas condições sejam atendidas seria E (and), pois o OU (or) precisa apenas de uma condição correta para ele dar True. (acabei percebendo uma coisa nesse código acabei  colocando um dos sinais da condição de baixo errada pois teria que ser maior que 1 e não menor que 1)

Comment: Com o seu último comentário em mente, releia a sua pergunta e, principalmente, seu código. Faz sentido você executar um laço de repetição enquanto o número for menor que 0 **e** maior que 24?

Comment: É realmente não faz, acabei me confundindo um pouco pois estava pensando com uma lógica parecida com Circuitos Digitais (and, or, xor, nor, xnor, nand e not). Obrigado pela ajuda e desculpa por qualquer coisa. Estou no meu primeiro semestre e tive meu primeiro contato com a programação agora.

Answer (score 5):

Você tem dois laços de repetição com `while`, que possuem a estrutura:

```
while condition:
    block
```

Onde o bloco de código `block` será executado enquanto a condição `condition` for verdadeira. Se a condição nunca for verdadeira, o bloco de código não será executado.

No seu caso, você definiu duas condições em conjunto com o operador `and`, porém as condições são exclusivas entre si e nunca serão ambas verdadeiras ao mesmo tempo.

```
while(numero <= 0 and numero > 24):
    ...
```

Ou o número é menor ou igual a 0 ou ele será maior que 24. As duas coisas ele não poderá ser.

Pelo código, você quer que seja solicitado ao usuário um valor enquanto ele não for válido, sendo válido apenas quando for maior que 0 e menor ou igual a 24. Para isso, o laço deveria ser:

```
while (numero <= 0 or numero > 24):
    ...
```

Ou

```
while not (numero > 0 and numero < 24):
    ...
```

Ou, da forma mais simplificada e legível:

```
while not (0 < numero <= 24):
    ...
```

Basta corrigir os seus dois laços com base nisso.